# Python client for accessing kubernetes cluster on GKE

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am struggling to programmatically access a kubernetes cluster running on Google Cloud. I have set up a service account and pointed `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to a corresponding credentials file. I managed to get the cluster and credentials as follows:

```py
import google.auth
from google.cloud.container_v1 import ClusterManagerClient
from kubernetes import client

credentials, project = google.auth.default(
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',])

credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())

cluster_manager = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
cluster = cluster_manager.get_cluster(project, 'us-west1-b', 'clic-cluster')
```

So far so good. But then I want to start using the kubernetes client:

```py
config = client.Configuration()
config.host = f'https://{cluster.endpoint}:443'
config.verify_ssl = False
config.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + credentials.token}
config.username = credentials._service_account_email

client.Configuration.set_default(config)

kub = client.CoreV1Api()
print(kub.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False))
```

And I get an error message like this:

***pods is forbidden: User "12341234123451234567" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope: Required "container.pods.list" permission.***

I found [this website](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/api-permissions) describing the `container.pods.list`, but I don't know where I should add it, or how it relates to the API scopes [described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error:

> pods is forbidden: User "12341234123451234567" cannot list resource
>   "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope: Required
>   "container.pods.list" permission.

it seems evident the user credentials you are trying to use, does not have permission on listing the pods.

The entire list of permissions mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam, states the following:

There are different Role which can play into account here:

- If you are able to get cluster, then it is covered with multiple **Role** sections like:  `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin`, `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Viewer`, `Kubernetes Engine Developer` & `Kubernetes Engine Viewer`
- Whereas, if you want to list pods `kub.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)` then you might need `Kubernetes Engine Viewer` access.

[image]

You should be able to add multiple roles.

Comment: That's it, I was missing the `Kubernetes Engine Viewer` role. Thanks!